# Matrix - characteristic polynom

Tags: matrices

Let $$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &  &  & -x_0 \\
1 & 0 &  & -x_1\\
 & 1 & 0& ... \\
 &  &... & -x_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

determine the characteristic polynom and decide wether A is diagonalizable. I know that the formula for determining c.p is $det(A-\lambda E)$ but how can I use this for the given matrix?

Comment: Check out the [Frobenius companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

As dxiv pointed out, the matrix is the companion matrix of the polynomial $$p(y)=y^n+x_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+x_1y+x_0$$

which is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix. Mostly, the exercise goes in the other direction : We have a polynomial and want to find a matrix having this characteristic polynomial. One matrix is the so-called companion-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Prove
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-\lambda&0&0&\dots&-x_0\\
1&-\lambda&0&\dots&-x_1\\
0 & 1 &-\lambda&\dots&-x_2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\vdots&--x_{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}=(-1)^n(\lambda^n+x_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\dots+x_1\lambda+x_0)$$
by induction on $n$, expanding  this determinant along the first row.